# ¿Cómo se llama los filtros o texturas que se le ponen a los contenedores de imágenes (Slides, divs, etc.)?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, imagen

Viendo algunos sitios web para referencia de proyectos, veo que hay una tendencia a cuanto las imágenes de portada y otros.Realmente quisiera saber como se llama esta tendencia,filtro o tipo de textura que se le aplica a las imágenes, así como donde puedo obtenerla.

**Anexo las imágenes de referencia:**

***Imagen Con "Filtro o Textura de puntos***
[image: Imagen Con filtro de puntos]
Si no se aprecia bien a lo que me refiero dejo el [enlace del sitio de ejemplo 1](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/jarvis-onepage-parallax-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/5370691?_ga=2.164906045.366981425.1510590368-902714744.1510590368)

***Imagen con "Filtro o Textura de rayas en diagonal***
[image: Filtro o textura en Diagonal]
Si no se aprecia bien a lo que me refiero dejo el [enlace del sitio de ejemplo 2](http://121cc.com/)

Espero y me de a entender.

Comment: [Mi sitio tiene esa funcionalidad](http://www.deiverbum.org), aunque en este caso es una especie de slider y las imágenes se les aplica algo de difuminación mediante CSS.

Comment: @A.Cedano Excelente, cada vez que me pongo a leer acerca de frontend quedo fascinado por los diseños, claro que surgen mis dudas y quisiera implementarlo en un proyecto, aunque realmente no he encontrado mucho sobre donde descargarlos o así, creo, que tendré que aprender hacerlos con photoshop

Comment: No sé si estás usando un CMS como WordPress u otro. Si es así hay muchos temas que los traen incorporados y luego tú los personalizas sin programar nada, solamente usando CSS. En mi caso ha sido así.

Comment: @A.Cedano, de hecho de un tema de wordpress me surgió la inquietud y quisiera usarlo en un proyecto creado desde 0, y es alli donde me surgió la duda de como implementarlo

Comment: No es tan complicado. Por ejemplo, lo de las imágenes que se van sucediendo se hace con jQuery: `jQuery("#featured").backstretch(["https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5639/30368995916_96b0033921_c.jpg", "https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8270/30353995236_67d9bf6625_z.jpg", "https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3673/33306759491_9e31e7d281_z.jpg"], { centeredY: false, duration: 5000, fade: 900  });` y todo lo demás es cuestión de CSS.

Comment: Voy a implementar todo esto en próximo proyecto para aprender mas de frontend, estoy empezando a conocer bootstrap y jquery, veamos que sale de todo esto, gracias @A.Cedano por los aportes que has dado, me han ayudado bastante.

Comment: De nada. Y si la respuesta de @PabloLozano responde a tu duda principal, no olvides marcarla como aceptada. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En inglés lo llaman "**pattern background overlay**" (cobertor con patrón de fondo, literalmente) y no es más que un div encima del vídeo con una imagen, que tiene el patrón de líneas o puntos, puesta como fondo y con una cierta transparencia para que se vea lo que hay detrás.
Puedes ver un ejemplo de cómo se hace en esta [web](http://www.dreevoo.com/content.php?id=2270)